# Abelian group - set $G$ of all complex roots of $1$, of all possible orders

Tags: group-theory, radicals, abelian-groups

Prove that the set G of all complex roots of $1$, of all possible orders is an abelian group with respect to multiplication.

So I wrote conditions to be an abelian group

> 1) $\forall a, b \in G, a*b \in G$
>
> 2) $\forall a,b,c \in G, (a*b)*c = a* (b*c)$
>
> 3) $\exists e, \forall a \in G, a*e=e*a=a$
>
> 4) $\exists b \forall a \in G, a*b = b*a=e$.
>
> 5) $\forall a, b \in G, a*b = b * a$.

I got the 1st and 2nd one. By the fact that $a=1^{1/n}*1^{1/m}=1^{1/n+1/m}$. So that still is a root of $1$ of some order $n+m$. Is that correct?

I stuck on the 3rd one with identity element. I was thinking about $e=1$ but $1^{1/n}*1=1^{1/n+1}$

Any tips?

// I think that I have realized that my approach to use $1^{1/n}$ instead of some $z^{n}=1$ might be incorrect.

Comment: Note first that $1/n+1/m=(n+m)/nm$. But this does not affect much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your justification is not correct. If $a^m=b^n=1$, then $(ab)^{mn}=(a^m)^n(b^n)^m=1$.

The identity element will be $1$, of course.

It must bechecked too that $a\in G\implies a^{-1}\in G$. But this is easy: $$a^n=1\implies(a^{-1})^n=\left(\frac1a\right)^n=\frac1{a^n}=\frac11=1.$$

Comment: Right I got it. I should have used $a^{n}$ not $1^{1/n}$ as element from the group. Thank you

Comment: I have one more question. How to explain that $a^{n}*b^{m}=(ab)^{nm}$ in that case. For example for naturals this thing it's not true.

Comment: @JamesSmith Why do you expect me to explain that? I never claimed that it is true. (For a good reason: it is *not* true.)

Comment: Nevermind I now see my mistake in understanding. We know that $a^{n}=1$ and $b^{m}=1$ so then $(ab)^{nm}=1$. However I can't still see how can we state that result of $a^{n}*b^{m}$ belongs to G?

Comment: @JamesSmith Because $(a^nb^m)^{nm}=1$.

Comment: I don't understand this notation. How is it a result of $a{^n}*b^{m}$? Maybe it's simple but I can't see it... And can we do this problem by showing that set off all complex numbers is an abelian group and then we check 2 conditions to be a subgroup?

Comment: @JamesSmith The answer to your second question is yes. Concerning the rest, I really don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Ok let's try to be more specific. We do have $a^{n}*b^{m}$. We know that $a^{n}=1$ and $b^{m}=1$ so as far as I see $a^{n}*b^{m}$ also hast to $=1$ and then $a^{n}*b^{m}$ is gonna be a root of 1 of a new degree. But how to write it more mathematically?

Comment: @JamesSmith If $a^n=b^m=1$, then $a^nb^m=1\times1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1^{1/n}\times 1^{1/m}=1^{(n+m)/nm}$, what you can really say is that the order of that element divides $nm$.

In your calculation with the identity, you've made a mistake. The number $1$ itself should be thought of as $1^0$, so it works as an identity. It is, after all, the familiar number $1$.

Comment: Can I even do this task using $1^{1/n}$? Coz I am not sure If is not something different than for example using $z^{n}$ (where $n$ is some natural number) (which I think is correct approach)

Comment: Now that you mention it, not every element of this group is strictly of the form $1^{1/n}$, because we have to pick a fixed meaning for that symbol. In other words, what do we mean by $1^{1/5}$? The number $1$ has five fifth roots, which reduces to four primitive ones if you don't count $1$ itself. Which one do we mean by $1${1/5}$?

Comment: A better way to talk about roots of unity is to think of them as $e^{2\pi i\frac{k}{n}}$, where $k$ and $n$ are integers with $n\ne 0$.

Comment: Yeah we don't really know what root is it in that case. So I think that it's wrong to use here $1^{1/n}$ instead of $z^{n}$ as there we have specified root.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Try to use the following charactherization of complex root of $1$:

- Complex root of $1$ can be written as $\exp\left( j\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)$ where $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For example to prove the $1$st property.

$$\exp\left( j_1\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)\exp\left( j_2\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)=\exp\left(( j_1+j_2)\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)$$

since $j_1+j_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, it is again a root of unity.

Comment: I think that might be to advanced for me. Thank you anyway